# TPLink Wifi Adapter LED Light Issue in Manjaro

Tags: wifi, manjaro, laptop

I have installed Manjaro XFCE in my Laptop, that also has Windows 8.1 in a dual-boot format.

I connect to Wifi using TP-Link (TL-WN823N) adapter and I have installed the driver (rtl8192eu.dkms).

**But, the issue is that the LED lights on the adapter never BLINK when using Manjaro, but, the adapter blinks when using Windows. So, why does it happen? And, what is the solution to this issue?Is it possible to use the Linux terminal to manually turn on the led of the Wifi adapter? If so, then please mention the steps.**

Below are some of the things that I tried but it didn't solve the issue.

```
sudo cp trigger /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.8/1-1.8:1.0/rtsx_usb_sdmmc.1.auto/leds/
modinfo 8192eu 
modprobe -c | grep -iE '8192eu'
modinfo cfg80211

sudo find / -type d \( -path "/home/user123/win8" -o -path "/home/user123/Edrive" \) -prune -o -print | grep -iE '8192eu\|led'

/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.8/1-1.8:1.0/rtsx_usb_sdmmc.1.auto/leds/mmc0::

sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness'

/sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192eu

/sys/module/8192eu

/sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192eu
```

```
***** $ hwinfo   # gives following output about TP Link

47: USB 00.0: 0282 WLAN controller
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: dwDZ.3tSB9EujntA
  Parent ID: ADDn.Wkj53szWOaA
 ***** SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-1.3:1.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "TP-Link TL-WN823N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8192EU]"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x2357 "TP-Link"
  Device: usb 0x0109 "TL-WN823N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8192EU]"
  Revision: "2.00"
  Serial ID: "00e04c000001"
  Driver: "rtl8192eu"
  Driver Modules: "8192eu"
  Device File: wlp0s29u1u3
  Features: WLAN
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  HW Address: 98:de:d0:0b:70:21
  Permanent HW Address: 98:de:d0:0b:70:21
  Link detected: yes
  WLAN channels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
  WLAN frequencies: 2.412 2.417 2.422 2.427 2.432 2.437 2.442 2.447 2.452 2.457 2.462 2.467 2.472
  WLAN bitrates: 1 2 5.5 11
  WLAN encryption modes: TKIP CCMP
  WLAN authentication modes: open wpa-psk wpa-eap
  Module Alias: "usb:v2357p0109d0200dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFFin00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: rtl8xxxu is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe rtl8xxxu"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: 8192eu is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe 8192eu"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #48 (Hub)
```